# Is it possible to store a math operation (+) in a variable and call on that variable as if you were directly using the operation itself

Tags: c#, variables, math

I know this is a weird question but here is a chunk of code to better explain what I am trying to do.

```
char plus = '+'; //Creating a variable assigning it to the + value.
//Instead of using + we use the variable plus and expect the same outcome.     
Console.WriteLine(1 + plus + 1); 
Console.ReadLine(); //Read the line.
```

But for some reason the console reads out 45...  Weird right?  So if you understand what I am trying to do can you explain and show me how?

Comment: "Weird right?" --- not at all. 43 is an ASCII for `+`. And `char` is implicitly converted to `int` in your expression.

Comment: You can create a delegate (lambda) that performs the actual operation and pass that around. Then call it when needed.

Comment: Your expectation is wrong.. you are not assigning `+`, the addition operator, to the variable `plus` - you are assigning it `'+'`, the ASCII character.

Comment: Are you trying to build a math parser?

Answer (score 5):

You can use delegates for this purpose:

```
 void int Add( int a, int b ) { return a + b; }
 void int Subtract( int a, int b ) { return a - b; }


 delegate int Operation( int a, int b );

 Operation myOp = Add;
 Console.WriteLine( myOp( 1, 1 ) ); // 2

 myOp = Subtract;
 Console.WriteLine( myOp( 1, 1 ) ); // 0
```

Also, you could use lambdas instead of named methods:

```
 myOp = (a,b) => a + b;
```

Answer (score 2):

In the case you are working with .Net 3.5 or above you can use `Func<>` and [lambdas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) (instead of needing to explicitly use delegates):

```
Func<int, int, int> plus = (a, b) => a + b; //Creating a variable assigning it to the + value.
//Instead of using + we use the variable plus and expect the same outcome.     
Console.WriteLine(plus(1, 1)); 
Console.ReadLine(); //Read the line.
```